# How to successfuly map non printable Zero Width Non Joiner on keyboard in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, language-support, special-characters

I am trying to type Urdu and for correct typography I need to type [Zero Width Non Joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) from the keyboard. I have already located it in the character map, copied it, and using the Custom Shortcuts (under System Settings -> keyboard) assigned it  a key combination Ctrl+Shift+Z.

The problem is that this solution is not working, as I am unable to achieve correct typography.

Comment: Which program do you use to write the text? LibreOffice Writer?

Comment: Yes LibreOffice Writer, gedit. I guess as I switch the keyboard, the key combination `Ctrl+Shift+Z` has no meanings and is not invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. I had added the keyboard by using the `Text Entry` option under All Settings. The keyboard I had added first `Urdu (Pakistan, CRULP)` has no key for typing ZWNJ. Where as the other keyboard that I added later `Urdu(Pakistan, NLA)` has the key mapped to `Ctrl+X`.

**Update:** This came into my notice now, `Ctrl+X` suddenly stopped functioning. i.e. it does not type ZWNJ anymore, most probably because `Ctrl+X` is reserved for the `cut` command. I don't know why it worked before. Anyway the new key combination that types ZWNJ is `Shift+X`.

[image: Text Entry]

[image: ZWNJ]